# Adjust CTRL-O movement position to ignore an intermediate position

Tags: vim, cursor-position

I have an extensive set of ViM key mappings for a text based game. One macro looks like this:

```
map <buffer> [[ g0k?UNIT [0-9a-zL]\+;<CR>zow
```

This achieves about that I want, with one drawback: When I press `CTRL-O`, the cursor is at the beginning of the line above where I typed `[[`. Pressing `CTRL-O` a second time gets me to a previous movement position, not the line where I started.

Is there a way to make the cursor move back to the position where I pressed `[[`, for example by making ViM not cache this intermediate movement step? Or is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your real problem, however, if your question is

> Is there a way ...making ViM not cache this intermediate movement step?

Yes, you should check `:keepjump`, it will bypass to store the position into jumplist when you did a jumpcommand.

P.S. `[[` is useful, you may want to reconsider the mapping keys.

Comment: Yes I know `[[` is useful, but this is not programming but the commands for a PBeM game. I will look into `keepjump` later, thx for the answer.